# How to compare a value from a created cell reference in for each loop in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, sampling

I am trying to sample rows based on the percentage of 1s in click(Column B) for every combination of unique values from banner_pos(Column E), device_type(Column O) and device_conn_type(Column P).

Something is wrong with the code at line 147 I guess.

Quick help very much appreciated.

Below is the code:

---

```
    Sub uniq()
Dim tmp, tmp1, tmp2 As String
Dim banr() As String
Dim banrrng As Range

Dim devtype() As String
Dim devtyperng As Range

Dim devcon() As String
Dim devconrng As Range

Set banrrng = Range("E2:E400") 'change the range to include all cells

   For Each cell In banrrng
      If (cell <> "") And (InStr(tmp, cell) = 0) Then
        tmp = tmp & cell & "|"
      End If
   Next cell


If Len(tmp) > 0 Then tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)

banr = Split(tmp, "|")

'For i = LBound(banr) To UBound(banr)
'    txt = txt & banr(i) & vbCrLf
'Next i
'MsgBox txt

'*****************************************************************************
'device type range
Set devtyperng = Range("O2:O400") 'change the range to include all cells

   For Each cell In devtyperng
      If (cell <> "") And (InStr(tmp1, cell) = 0) Then
        tmp1 = tmp1 & cell & "|"
      End If
   Next cell

If Len(tmp1) > 0 Then tmp1 = Left(tmp1, Len(tmp1) - 1)

devtype = Split(tmp1, "|")

'For i = LBound(devtype) To UBound(devtype)
'   MsgBox devtype(i)
'Next i

'*****************************************************************************
'device connection range
Set devconrng = Range("P2:P400") 'change the range to include all cells

   For Each cell In devconrng
      If (cell <> "") And (InStr(tmp2, cell) = 0) Then
        tmp2 = tmp2 & cell & "|"
      End If
   Next cell

If Len(tmp2) > 0 Then tmp2 = Left(tmp2, Len(tmp2) - 1)

devcon = Split(tmp2, "|")

'For i = LBound(devcon) To UBound(devcon)
'   MsgBox devcon(i)
'Next i

'**********************************************************************************888888
'counting number of clicks
Dim clkcntR As Range
Set clkcntR = Range("B2:B400")
Dim clkcnt As Single
clkcnt = Application.CountIf(clkcntR, 1)
MsgBox (clkcnt)

'defining the count array across banner, devicetype and deviceconnection

'Getting count array size
Dim cntArrSiz As Integer 'if any error change type to long
cntArrSiz = 1
cntArrSiz = cntArrSiz * (Application.CountA(banr))
cntArrSiz = cntArrSiz * (Application.CountA(devtype))
cntArrSiz = cntArrSiz * (Application.CountA(devcon))
MsgBox (cntArrSiz)

Dim cntArr() As Single 'if any error change type to long
ReDim cntArr(cntArrSiz)

Dim PropArr() As Single 'if any error change type to long
ReDim PropArr(cntArrSiz)

Dim PercArr(), sampSize, rndSize As Integer
ReDim PercArr(cntArrSiz)
sampSize = 25
rndSize = 400

Dim loopCount As Integer ' if any error change type to long
loopCount = 1


For Each cell1 In banr
    For Each cell2 In devtype
        For Each cell3 In devcon

        cntArr(loopCount) = Application.CountIfs(clkcntR, 1, banrrng, cell1, devtyperng, cell2, devconrng, cell3)
        'MsgBox "cntarr" & cntArr(loopCount)
        PropArr(loopCount) = Round((cntArr(loopCount) / clkcnt), 2)
        'MsgBox "PropArr" & PropArr(loopCount)

        PercArr(loopCount) = Round((PropArr(loopCount) * sampSize), 0)
       ' MsgBox "PercArr: " & PercArr(loopCount)

        loopCount = loopCount + 1

        Next
    Next
Next

Randomize 'Initialize Random number seed
Dim MyRows() As Integer    ' Declare dynamic array.
Dim numRows, percRows, nxtRow, nxtRnd, chkRnd, copyRow, percCount As Integer

percCount = 1
    ReDim MyRows(sampSize)
'Create Random numbers and fill array
Dim storeRow As Integer
 storeRow = 1

 Dim evilRng As Range
 Dim cellref As String
Set evilRng = Range("B2:P400")

For Each cell1 In banr
    For Each cell2 In devtype
        For Each cell3 In devcon

     For nxtRow = 1 To PercArr(percCount)
getNew:
'Generate Random number
      nxtRnd = CInt(Int((rndSize * Rnd()) + 1))
      'MsgBox "next random number" & nxtRnd
'Loop through array, checking for Duplicates
       'For chkRnd = 1 To storeRow
'Get new number if Duplicate is found
        If MyRows(chkRnd) = 1 Then GoTo getNew

        cellref = Format(evilRng.Cells(nxtRnd, 5))

        If StrComp(cell1, cellref) <> 0 Then GoTo getNew  ' ***********This is where the error is*******************************8



       'Next
'Add element if Random number is unique
      MyRows(storeRow) = nxtRnd
      storeRow = storeRow + 1
   Next
        percCount = percCount + 1

           Next
       Next
    Next

   storeRow = storeRow - 1

   'Loop through Array, copying rows to Sheet2
     For copyRow = 1 To storeRow
       Worksheets("train").Rows(MyRows(copyRow)).EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(copyRow, 1)
     Next
   End Sub ' code working until sampling
```

Comment: What error message get you?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that one of your cells has an error such as #NUM! in it. Replace using these two lines:

```
cellref = Format(evilRng.Cells(nxtRnd, 5))
If StrComp(cell1, cellref) <> 0 Then GoTo getNew
```

With these lines:

```
cellref = CStr(evilRng.Cells(nxtRnd, 5))
If StrComp(CStr(cell1.Value), cellref) <> 0 Then GoTo getNew
```